# compare 2 string gives false as result even if they are same

Tags: javascript, string, equality

I cant figure this out. Might be a silly error from my end. here is the scenario.

I have one variable 'data' whose value is as follows.

```
Select,Row_no,Comments
```

Another variable as output, whose value is exactly same as above.

```
Select,Row_no,Comments
```

I have also checked the type of variable using typeof. It shows string to both variable.

Now, i tried to compare if these strings are equal. but it never showed 'true' even if they are exactly same.

tried the following

```
console.log(data === output); // gave false as output
console.log(data == output); // gave false as output
console.log(data.localeCompare(output));  // gave -1 as output. 0 means equal in this case. but it gives -1
```

anything i am doing wrong while checking if these 2 strings are equal ?

Comment: Try comparing length as well

Comment: What do you get when you try `console.log( data.trim() == output.trim() );`?

Comment: This should never be the case, try the same in browser console and see if it works.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that they are the same? Do you have any leading or trailing white-space that a `trim()` statement might need to clean up?

Comment: @sbeliv01- trim statement helped. but if i check the console, there is absolutely no whitespaces. strange !!

Comment: probably you are making some kind mistake. `console.log(data === output);` should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest check length and do

```
 console.log(data.trim() == output.trim());
```